# Как сделать словообразовательный разбор?

Tags: словообразование

Как сделать словообразовательный разбор слова "окрашивание"? 
Это значит определить, каким способом оно образовано?
То есть приставочно-суффиксальный и другие, да?

Comment: Да! Можете прочитать здесь:[ Морфемный и словообразовательный разбор слова] (http://www.licey.net/russian/phonetics/2_15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что такое *окрашивание*? Это результат действия по глаголу *окрашивать*.

**Окрашива**ние - **окрашива**ть - суффиксальный -  от основы глагола **окрашива-**
с помощью суфф. **-НИ-(ниj)**.

Comment: использование значит тоже будет суффиксальный способ, да? 
от слова использовать...

Comment: да,и вообще, если суфф. -ни-, ний-,нечего сомневаться, способ будет суффиксальный